rust-analyzer in Visual Studio Enterprise for aarch64-pc-windows-msvc target
When opening a rust solution, Visual Studio reports "error: toolchain 'nightly--aarch64-pc-windows-msvc' does not contain component 'rust-analyzer-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc' for target 'aarch64-pc-windows-msvc'" even though the rust-analyzer-aarch64-pc-windows-msvc component is installed (presently it is only available from the nightly build.)
How does one change the setting in VS to point to the correct rust-analyzer? (analyzer is set as the first entry in user PATH.)
Versions
Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (ARM 64-bit) Version 17.12.3
rustup 1.27.1, rusc 1.83.0
Was expecting VS to execute the rust-analyzer binary from the default target.
Rustup ouptut
PS C:\Users\User.Name> rustup target list
aarch64-apple-darwin
...
aarch64-pc-windows-msvc (installed)
...
arm64ec-pc-windows-msvc (installed)

PS C:\Users\User.Name> rustup toolchain list
stable-aarch64-pc-windows-msvc
nightly-aarch64-pc-windows-msvc (default)

PS C:\Users\User.Name> rustup component add rust-analyzer
info: component 'rust-analyzer' for target 'aarch64-pc-windows-msvc' is up to date

